How to run linux command in jobs, when to run bash script

I want to run those command in linux jobs, so when I tyep "jobs", I can mannage those jobs, how to do it ( in bash script)

Please, don't post images of text

also, why all these execs? What is the purpose they serve?

Please explain what "manage these jobs" would mean!

To summarize, we have no idea what you're trying to accomplish and getting a sinking sensation that neither do you. Please clarify your question and explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish -- presumably setting up a number of homebrew SSH-based port forwards to break through a firewall.

Job control scope in bash is limited to the shell you run the jobs in.
What you posted looks like a text of a shell script. So when you run that script, it is run in separate instance of bash that exits right after your script ends. So these commands have been run as jobs, but these jobs belonged to a shell that no longer exists and can't provide job control - not to a shell you are typing your commands in.
If you want these commands to be visible as jobs in your current shell, you have also to run your shell script in your current shell, without spawning a new shell. So instead of simply running your script like eg.
./script.sh

you have to source the script, ie. execute its contents within the context of the current shell:
. ./script.sh

(yes, . is a bash command that tells the shell to source the script!)
Then your ssh commands should be visible as jobs.
BTW. the exec commands in your script are completely unneeded. You may remove them while still have the desired effect.
